# Characterization of continuous functionals on Fréchet spaces in terms of a seminorm

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I've recently encountered Fréchet spaces for the first time, and I was wondering if it remains true that a functional $T \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $S$ a Fréchet space, is continuous if for all $\phi \in S$  we have

$$|T\phi| \leq c\|\phi\|_S$$

where $\|\cdot\|_S$ denotes a semi-norm on the $S$ space. The reason I'm asking is that I have only ever seen the above result formulated for Banach spaces, and I was curious if it extends naturally?

Comment: @kimchilover Let's say that $S$ is the Schwarz space, and the norm is one of the semi-norms on that space.

Comment: The way you had phrased it made it seem like you didn't know the difference between a B space and an F space.  I'll remove my earlier comments, and then this one later.

Answer (score 3):

This is true, with the caveat that the semi-norm need  not be one from whatever collection of seminorms was originally used to define the topology on $S$. Also, this is true for any [locally convex space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space); it need not be a [Fréchet space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space) (which requires in addition a compatible complete translation-invariant metric).

**Claim**: In a locally convex space $X$ whose topology is defined by seminorms $\{p_\alpha\}$, a linear functional $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if it is majorized by a finite combination of seminorms: $$|f(x)|\le M\max (p_1(x),\dots, p_n(x))$$ 
*Proof*: The set $U=\{x : |f(x)|<1\}$ is an open set containing $0$. By the definition of LCS topology, $U$  it contains a neighborhood of $0$ the form $\{x \colon \max_{k=1, \dots, n}  p_k(x)<\epsilon\}$. The conclusion with $M=1/\epsilon$. $\quad \Box$

It remains to left $p(x) = \max (p_1(x),\dots, p_n(x))$ and you get the desired seminorm.

#### Example

This is an example to show that one can't always pick just one of "original" seminorms. Let $S$ be the space $C(\mathbb{R})$ of all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with seminorms 
$$
p_n(f) = \sup_{[n, n+1]}|f|,\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
These seminorms induce the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets. The linear functional $T(f) = \int_{0}^3 f(x)\,dx$ is continuous on $S$, but there is no single seminorm $p_n$ that dominates $|T(f)|$; one has to use $\max(p_0, p_1, p_2)$.